# How to find the ratio of some areas in a triangle

Tags: geometry

in the figure below :

[image]
Let :

$$DE \parallel BC$$

$$|AE|=c \ \ \ |AD|=e \ \ \ |DC|=b \ \ \ |BC|=a \ \ \ |BE|= d$$

$$\dfrac{S_{   \triangle AED}}{S_{   \triangle DEC}}=x$$

$$\dfrac{S_{   \triangle AED}}{S_{   \triangle BEC}}=y$$

Then what is $x,y$ ?

---

I know that :

since $DE \parallel BC$ So :

$$\dfrac{|AE|}{|AB|}=\dfrac{|AD|}{|AC|}=\dfrac{|DE|}{|BC|}$$

And :

$$\dfrac{|AE|}{|BE|}=\dfrac{|AD|}{|DC|}$$

Now what ?

Comment: According to your diagram, the area of $AEB$ is zero, hence $x=y=0$.

Comment: Does $S$ mean area?

Comment: $AEB$ is just a line ($E$ is straight between $A$ and $B$ vertices). So something goes wrong... Or it is a joke and $x=y=0$ because of $S \triangle AEB = 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. i'm sorry . I edited

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. $S=\text{area}$

Answer (score 3):

If $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are two triangles sharing an altitude, the ratio of their areas equals the ratio of their base lengths. Similarly, if $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$ share a base, the ratio of their areas equals the ratio of their altitudes. It follows that
$$ x=\frac{[AED]}{[DEC]}=\frac{e}{b},\qquad y=\frac{[AED]}{[BEC]}=\frac{[AED]}{[AEC]}\cdot\frac{[AEC]}{[BEC]}=\frac{e}{e+b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}.$$ 
The constraint $DE\parallel BC$ further gives $\frac{e}{e+b}=\frac{c}{c+d}$ by Thales' theorem.

Comment: Note that $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{e}{b}$.

Comment: Also, there is no $\Delta_1$ or $\Delta_2$ in the question. We can guess what you mean, but it is not entirely clear.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: that is equivalent to $\frac{e}{e+b}=\frac{c}{c+d}$ by reciprocating, subtracting one and reciprocating again.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ in my answer are just two triangles fulfilling some constraints. The ratios wanted by the OP are clearly denoted as such - I am using the notation $[XYZ]$ for the area of the triangle $XYZ$.